# keeping QR scanning history using ZBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, qr-code

I am using ZBar to develop a QR scanning application . I am using XCode 4.2

is there a way to keep the history of the last 10 scanned items ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use persistent storage. Read Core Data programming [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html)